# Using custom types in Godot with GDExtension

Tags: c++, godot

Working on a Godot 4 addon with GDExtension, I find that I cannot compile my source code due to type errors that I don't know exactly how to work around or fix.

I have the following code:

```
// register_types.cpp
#include "register_types.h"
#include "../godot-cpp/gdextension/gdextension_interface.h"
#include "../godot-cpp/include/godot_cpp/core/class_db.hpp"
#include "../godot-cpp/include/godot_cpp/core/defs.hpp"
#include "../godot-cpp/include/godot_cpp/godot.hpp"

#include "poker.hpp"

void initialize_gdextension_types(godot::ModuleInitializationLevel p_level) {
  if (p_level != godot::MODULE_INITIALIZATION_LEVEL_SCENE) {
    return;
  }
  godot::ClassDB::register_class<Poker>();
  godot::ClassDB::register_class<SingleHandRankingEvaluationResult>();
}

void uninitialize_gdextension_types(godot::ModuleInitializationLevel p_level) {
  if (p_level != godot::MODULE_INITIALIZATION_LEVEL_SCENE) {
    return;
  }
}

extern "C" {
// Initialization
// NOTE: I don't think we need to touch anything here
GDExtensionBool GDE_EXPORT
poker_utils_library_init(GDExtensionInterfaceGetProcAddress p_get_proc_address,
                         GDExtensionClassLibraryPtr p_library,
                         GDExtensionInitialization *r_initialization) {
  godot::GDExtensionBinding::InitObject init_obj(p_get_proc_address, p_library,
                                                 r_initialization);
  init_obj.register_initializer(initialize_gdextension_types);
  init_obj.register_terminator(uninitialize_gdextension_types);
  init_obj.set_minimum_library_initialization_level(
      godot::MODULE_INITIALIZATION_LEVEL_CORE);

  return init_obj.init();
}
}



// poker.hpp
#include "../godot-cpp/gdextension/gdextension_interface.h"
#include "../godot-cpp/include/godot_cpp/core/class_db.hpp"
#include "../godot-cpp/include/godot_cpp/core/defs.hpp"
#include "../godot-cpp/include/godot_cpp/godot.hpp"
#include "../godot-cpp/include/godot_cpp/templates/vector.hpp"

class Poker : public godot::Object {
  GDCLASS(Poker, godot::Object);

protected:
  static void _bind_methods();

public:
  static godot::PackedStringArray getDeck();
  static godot::PackedStringArray getDeckShuffled();
  static SingleHandRankingEvaluationResult
  singleHandRankEvaluation(const godot::PackedStringArray cards);
};

// ...

struct SingleHandRankingEvaluationResult : public godot::Object {
  GDCLASS(SingleHandRankingEvaluationResult, godot::Object);

private:
  int HandRanking;
  godot::String Error;

protected:
  static void _bind_methods();

public:
  void set_hand_ranking(int ranking);
  int get_hand_ranking();
  void set_error(godot::String error);
  godot::String get_error();
};

// poker.cpp
#include "poker.hpp"
#include "../src/deck.hpp"
#include "../src/hand-evaluation.hpp"
#include <string>
#include <vector>

void SingleHandRankingEvaluationResult::set_hand_ranking(int ranking) {
  this->HandRanking = ranking;
}

int SingleHandRankingEvaluationResult::get_hand_ranking() {
  return this->HandRanking;
}

void SingleHandRankingEvaluationResult::set_error(godot::String error) {
  this->Error = error;
}

godot::String SingleHandRankingEvaluationResult::get_error() {
  return this->Error;
};

void SingleHandRankingEvaluationResult::_bind_methods() {
  godot::ClassDB::bind_method(
      godot::D_METHOD("set_hand_ranking"),
      &SingleHandRankingEvaluationResult::set_hand_ranking);
  godot::ClassDB::bind_method(
      godot::D_METHOD("get_hand_ranking"),
      &SingleHandRankingEvaluationResult::get_hand_ranking);
  godot::ClassDB::bind_method(godot::D_METHOD("set_error"),
                              &SingleHandRankingEvaluationResult::set_error);
  godot::ClassDB::bind_method(godot::D_METHOD("get_error"),
                              &SingleHandRankingEvaluationResult::get_error);

  godot::ClassDB::add_property(
      "SingleHandRankingEvaluationResult",
      godot::PropertyInfo(godot::Variant::INT, "hand_ranking"),
      "set_hand_ranking", "get_hand_ranking");
  godot::ClassDB::add_property(
      "SingleHandRankingEvaluationResult",
      godot::PropertyInfo(godot::Variant::STRING, "error"), "set_error",
      "get_error");
}

SingleHandRankingEvaluationResult
Poker::singleHandRankEvaluation(const godot::PackedStringArray cards) {
  poker::Cards all_cards;

  for (const auto &card : cards) {
    all_cards.push_back(std::string(godot2stdstr(card)));
  }

  auto result = poker::singleHandRankEvaluation(all_cards);
  if (std::holds_alternative<poker::Error>(result)) {
    SingleHandRankingEvaluationResult evaluation;

    evaluation.set_error(std::get<poker::Error>(result).message.c_str());
    return evaluation;
  }

  int ranking = std::get<int>(result);
  SingleHandRankingEvaluationResult evaluation;
  evaluation.set_hand_ranking(ranking);

  return evaluation;
};
```

when running `scons` I get these errors:

```
➜  scons
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
Auto-detected 12 CPU cores available for build parallelism. Using 11 cores by default. You can override it with the -j argument.
Building for architecture x86_64 on platform linux
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
scons: `godot-cpp/bin/libgodot-cpp.linux.template_debug.x86_64.a' is up to date.
g++ -o godot/poker.os -c -std=c++17 -fPIC -Wwrite-strings -m64 -march=x86-64 -O2 -fPIC -DLINUX_ENABLED -DUNIX_ENABLED -DDEBUG_ENABLED -DDEBUG_METHODS_ENABLED -DNDEBUG -Igodot-cpp/gdextension -Igodot-cpp/include -Igodot-cpp/gen/include -I/nix/store/5hch4vqzwan8ksab4pfpyrbb7wvvv3ad-cxxtest-4.4/include -I/nix/store/7nbh3b6hhjqjs3nfy529g38l85iv46i9-openssl-3.0.11-dev/include -Isrc -Iompeval/omp -Igodot godot/poker.cpp
In file included from godot/../godot-cpp/include/godot_cpp/core/class_db.hpp:38,
                 from godot/poker.hpp:5,
                 from godot/poker.cpp:1:
godot-cpp/include/godot_cpp/core/method_bind.hpp: In instantiation of 'GDExtensionVariantType godot::MethodBindTRS<R, P>::gen_argument_type(int) const [with R = SingleHandRankingEvaluationResult; P = {godot::PackedStringArray}]':
godot-cpp/include/godot_cpp/core/method_bind.hpp:674:33:   required from here
godot-cpp/include/godot_cpp/core/method_bind.hpp:678:71: error: incomplete type 'godot::GetTypeInfo<SingleHandRankingEvaluationResult, void>' used in nested name specifier
  678 |                         return GDExtensionVariantType(GetTypeInfo<R>::VARIANT_TYPE);
      |                                                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~
godot-cpp/include/godot_cpp/core/method_bind.hpp: In instantiation of 'godot::PropertyInfo godot::MethodBindTRS<R, P>::gen_argument_type_info(int) const [with R = SingleHandRankingEvaluationResult; P = {godot::PackedStringArray}]':
godot-cpp/include/godot_cpp/core/method_bind.hpp:682:23:   required from here
godot-cpp/include/godot_cpp/core/method_bind.hpp:688:62: error: incomplete type 'godot::GetTypeInfo<SingleHandRankingEvaluationResult, void>' used in nested name specifier
  688 |                         return GetTypeInfo<R>::get_class_info();
      |                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
godot-cpp/include/godot_cpp/core/method_bind.hpp: In instantiation of 'GDExtensionClassMethodArgumentMetadata godot::MethodBindTRS<R, P>::get_argument_metadata(int) const [with R = SingleHandRankingEvaluationResult; P = {godot::PackedStringArray}]':
godot-cpp/include/godot_cpp/core/method_bind.hpp:697:49:   required from here
godot-cpp/include/godot_cpp/core/method_bind.hpp:701:48: error: incomplete type 'godot::GetTypeInfo<SingleHandRankingEvaluationResult, void>' used in nested name specifier
  701 |                         return GetTypeInfo<R>::METADATA;
      |                                                ^~~~~~~~
In file included from godot-cpp/include/godot_cpp/core/method_bind.hpp:34:
godot-cpp/include/godot_cpp/core/binder_common.hpp: In instantiation of 'void godot::call_with_variant_args_static_ret(R (*)(P ...), const Variant**, Variant&, GDExtensionCallError&, IndexSequence<Is ...>) [with R = SingleHandRankingEvaluationResult; P = {PackedStringArray}; long unsigned int ...Is = {0}]':
godot-cpp/include/godot_cpp/core/binder_common.hpp:584:35:   required from 'void godot::call_with_variant_args_static_ret_dv(R (*)(P ...), const void* const*, int, Variant&, GDExtensionCallError&, const std::vector<Variant>&) [with R = SingleHandRankingEvaluationResult; P = {PackedStringArray}; GDExtensionConstVariantPtr = const void*]'
godot-cpp/include/godot_cpp/core/method_bind.hpp:707:39:   required from 'godot::Variant godot::MethodBindTRS<R, P>::call(GDExtensionClassInstancePtr, const void* const*, GDExtensionInt, GDExtensionCallError&) const [with R = SingleHandRankingEvaluationResult; P = {godot::PackedStringArray}; GDExtensionClassInstancePtr = void*; GDExtensionConstVariantPtr = const void*; GDExtensionInt = long int]'
godot-cpp/include/godot_cpp/core/method_bind.hpp:705:18:   required from here
godot-cpp/include/godot_cpp/core/binder_common.hpp:546:15: error: no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'godot::Variant' and 'SingleHandRankingEvaluationResult')
  546 |         r_ret = (p_method)(VariantCasterAndValidate<P>::cast(p_args, Is, r_error)...);
      |         ~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from godot-cpp/include/godot_cpp/core/property_info.hpp:38,
                 from godot-cpp/include/godot_cpp/core/object.hpp:36,
                 from godot-cpp/include/godot_cpp/core/method_ptrcall.hpp:36,
                 from godot-cpp/include/godot_cpp/core/binder_common.hpp:36:
godot-cpp/include/godot_cpp/variant/variant.hpp:252:18: note: candidate: 'godot::Variant& godot::Variant::operator=(const godot::Variant&)'
  252 |         Variant &operator=(const Variant &other);
      |                  ^~~~~~~~
godot-cpp/include/godot_cpp/variant/variant.hpp:252:43: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'SingleHandRankingEvaluationResult' to 'const godot::Variant&'
  252 |         Variant &operator=(const Variant &other);
      |                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~
godot-cpp/include/godot_cpp/variant/variant.hpp:253:18: note: candidate: 'godot::Variant& godot::Variant::operator=(godot::Variant&&)'
  253 |         Variant &operator=(Variant &&other);
      |                  ^~~~~~~~
godot-cpp/include/godot_cpp/variant/variant.hpp:253:38: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'SingleHandRankingEvaluationResult' to 'godot::Variant&&'
  253 |         Variant &operator=(Variant &&other);
      |                            ~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~
godot-cpp/include/godot_cpp/core/binder_common.hpp: In instantiation of 'void godot::call_with_ptr_args_static_method_ret_helper(R (*)(P ...), const void* const*, void*, IndexSequence<Is ...>) [with R = SingleHandRankingEvaluationResult; P = {PackedStringArray}; long unsigned int ...Is = {0}; GDExtensionConstTypePtr = const void*]':
godot-cpp/include/godot_cpp/core/binder_common.hpp:594:54:   required from 'void godot::call_with_ptr_args_static_method_ret(R (*)(P ...), const void* const*, void*) [with R = SingleHandRankingEvaluationResult; P = {PackedStringArray}; GDExtensionConstTypePtr = const void*]'
godot-cpp/include/godot_cpp/core/method_bind.hpp:713:39:   required from 'void godot::MethodBindTRS<R, P>::ptrcall(GDExtensionClassInstancePtr, const void* const*, GDExtensionTypePtr) const [with R = SingleHandRankingEvaluationResult; P = {godot::PackedStringArray}; GDExtensionClassInstancePtr = void*; GDExtensionConstTypePtr = const void*; GDExtensionTypePtr = void*]'
godot-cpp/include/godot_cpp/core/method_bind.hpp:711:15:   required from here
godot-cpp/include/godot_cpp/core/binder_common.hpp:589:28: error: 'encode' is not a member of 'godot::PtrToArg<SingleHandRankingEvaluationResult>'
  589 |         PtrToArg<R>::encode(p_method(PtrToArg<P>::convert(p_args[Is])...), r_ret);
      |         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
scons: *** [godot/poker.os] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

So I have to ask:

1. What am I doing wrong that `GetTypeInfo` is unable to work with my custom type?
2. What's the easiest way to get my type up and running and be able to compile?
3. Any alternative to returning errors with GDExtensive?
4. Is `godot::Object` the best type to inherit of for your `struct`? godot-cpp branch 4.1 has no `godot::Resource` type for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `set_error` function expects a `std::string` as parameter but you bound it with `ClassDB::bind_method` and Godot can't directly convert between `std::string` and `godot::String`.

Whenever you bind methods for Godot's ClassBD you must use Godot API types (so any type available to GDScript). If you need to be able to use `std::string` consider defining a separate method for that (Not sure if an overload would be handled correctly atm.)

Edit: To answer your 4th question: `Resource` still exists but every Godot class has its own header so `Resource` would be in `<godot_cpp/classes/resource.hpp>`

As it turns out the Godot method binder only allows `godot::Object` pointers as return and parameter type. If a type inherits `godot::RefCounted` the `godot::Ref<T>` class can be used as smart pointer that is correctly updated when Godot accesses the object.

Comment: fixed that and the number of errors went down; however, there are still issues with `encode` missing and my struct not being compatible with `godot::Variant`. What am I expected to do to solve these issues, exactly?

Comment: @shackra Which version are you building for (what tag of godot-cpp did you checkout?)

Comment: for `4.1`, that's the branch of godot-cpp I'm using.

Comment: Without updated code and error I can only guess but I suspect you're still using `std::string` with `String` directly. (In particular the condition body of your singleHandRankEvaluation seems prone to that)

Comment: I edited my original question with the updated code and error message from the compiler

Comment: After replicating your setup, I get the error as well. It would seem the ClassDB binder currently does not support static methods that return Objects (`godot::Object` yielded the same error, however other Godot types like, `godot::String` and `godot::Array` work). I'll setup a minimum reproduction project and submit an issue for this. Until then I recommend handling such methods via a singleton instance.

Comment: Thank you! please update your answer to include that tibit, so I can mark it as the answer to my question.

Comment: Updated the comment with a description of the found behaviour and the mentioned workaround.

Comment: Disregard what I've said about the bug being on Godot's end, as it turns out `godot::Object` is not a valid API type, but `godot::Object *` is. This is inline with godot-cpp's goal to provide a smooth way to translate module code and gdextension code between each other.

Comment: Roger that. I actually moved to `godot::RefCounted` instead of `godot::Object` and now things compiled well.